# Issues while upgrade to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I am upgrading to `Magento 2.2.5 to Magento 2.3.0`, Some of the third party module is giving error while `composer update`. `my current php version is 7.2.12`

Can you please help me out? Please refer below screenshot:

I have also tried `composer require [ModuleName] 2.3.0 --no-update`
But it is giving package not found error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package ModuleName in a version matching
>   2.3.0

[image]

Comment: what is your composer version?

Comment: Composer version 1.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check your third party extension's `composer.json` file and find required php version, if your current php version not available in "require" then please add latest version **"7.2.12"** and also add framework version **"102.0.*"**

```
"require": {
        "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0|~7.2.12",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.0.*|100.1.*|100.2.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*|100.1.*|101.0.*|102.0.*"
    },
```

After that please find your third party extension name on `/vendor/composer/installed.json` file, you can see php version and framework version in this file So please add php version in "require" same as per module's `composer.json` file

after above changes please run `composer update` command and let me know if you get any issue.

Thanks

Comment: You must have PHP 7.2 installed for Magento 2.3 (PHP 7.1.3+ is also supported)

Comment: I have installed PHP 7.2, and temporary remove those module and seems its working fine now, i will install those module later on. Thanks